# How to read only the first X bytes of a message using Golang

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

Say I have some WS code like so:

```
var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
}


func handleConnections(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer ws.Close()

    for {
        messageType, message, err := ws.ReadMessage()
         // above works...
       // I want to read the first 20 bytes, not the whole message
      
    }
}
```

how an I read the first X bytes, not the whole message?

Answer (score 3):

Use [NextReader](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.NextReader) to get an [io.Reader](https://godoc.org/io#Reader) on the message.  Read X bytes from the reader.

```
const X = 20
for {
    messageType, r, err := ws.NextReader()
    if err != nil { 
        // Failure reading message.
        break 
    }
    var buf [X]byte
    n, err := io.ReadFull(r, buf[:])
    if err != nil && err != io.ErrUnexpectedEOF {
       // Failure reading message.
       break
    }   

    // The variable prefix is the first X bytes of
    // message or the entire message if message is
    // shorter than X bytes.
    prefix := buf[:n]
  
    // Do something with prefix. 
}
```

If you want to handle short messages as an error, then change the error check to:

```
    if err == io.ErrUnexpectedEOF {
       // Handle short message.
       continue // or break if short message is a hard failure.
    } else if err != nil {
       // Failure reading message
       break
    }
```

Comment: `ErrUnexpectedEOF` happens when you have read some bytes but not all that you expected and probably shouldn't be ignored. An alternative to above is to set `X` to the size of the prefix you expect and then expect `err != nil`. If that is successfull you read the rest (E.g. in a TLV scenario).

Comment: @MazenHarake The answer handles `ErrUnexpectedEOF` by slicing the `buf` to the actual number of bytes read and assigning to the result to variable `prefix`.  The variable `prefix`  is the first X bytes of message or the entire message if message is shorter than X bytes.

Comment: I understand what it does, my point was just that if you ignore `ErrUnexcpetedEOF` then you don't know if you read 2 bytes or 20 bytes (unless you check the length of course). That is why I meant that in a TLV situation it is better to read the type and length values explicitly so that you know you got the bytes you needed. Anyway I saw you updated the answer :) cheers